# How to generate public and private Key in RSA vb.net

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, cryptography, rsa

How to generate public and private Key in RSA vb.net for client server program I use this code but it does not work correctly when run in network

```vb
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

' class to allow the use of RSA encryption
Public NotInheritable Class RSA
    Private RSA As RSACryptoServiceProvider

    Sub New(ByVal publicKey As String)
        ' Initialize the crypto provider.
        RSA = New RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)
        If publicKey <> "" Then
            RSA.FromXmlString(publicKey)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function getPublicKey()
        ' retrieve the generated public key
        Dim publicStr As String = RSA.ToXmlString(False)
        Return publicStr
    End Function

    Public Function getPrivateKey()
        ' retrieve the generated private key
        Dim privateStr As String = RSA.ToXmlString(True)
        Return privateStr
    End Function

    Public Function EncryptData(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal publicKey As String)
        ' encrypt plaintext to encrypted byte array
        Try
            RSA.FromXmlString(publicKey)
            Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding
            Dim textbytes As Byte()
            textbytes = encoder.GetBytes(plainText)
            Dim encryptedBytes As Byte() = RSA.Encrypt(textbytes, False)
            Return encryptedBytes
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return ""
    End Function

    Public Function DecryptData(ByVal encryptedBytes As Byte(), ByVal privateKey As String)
        ' function to decrypt byte array to plaintext
        Try
            RSA.FromXmlString(privateKey)
            Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding
            Dim plainBytes As Byte() = RSA.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, False)
            Dim plainText As String = encoder.GetString(plainBytes)
            Return plainText
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return ""
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: i don't really understand your question ... you are asking how to genereate the rsa key? ... you already have that ... `New RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)` will give you a configured csp instance with a newly created 2048 bit rsa key...

Comment: yes i ask how to generate RSA key

Comment: @FatimaIE So what's the problem with the code you've shown?

Comment: @ArtjomB. can not genarete private key from public key

Comment: @FatimaIE ... this is by design, and the whole point of asymetric cryptography ... with the public key alone you are unable to get the private key ... IF there would be a solution to your problem, RSA would be broken and useless

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42  so what alternative new to generate Key ?

Comment: You never told us what you want to achieve

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 for  secure email application

Comment: You need to read up on pki ... public key infrastructure... every recipient needs to create a keypair and while the private key will be kept secret the public keys are distributed via the pki ... pub key encrypts ... Private key decrypts